# Caching Compiled Expression Delegates

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

**Backstory:** Throughout our project we constantly find ourselves using the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator` object as well as attributes to validate properties passed in to our API. The `Validator` object requires passing in the property name as well as the value, which is fair, but we are all a little grossed out by the [constantly-increasing] number of *magic strings* being passed around for these property names. Not only this entails the risk of mistyping the property name, it also reduces maintainability in the case that one of those properties get renamed (again, there are way too many of them).

To automatically resolve the member name, I created this helper method (for the sake of simplicity, let's assume I'm only dealing with reference-type properties, hence the `P: class` constraint):

```
public static P ValidateProperty<T, P>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, P>> member, List<ValidationResult> results, Func<P, P> onValidCallback = null)
    where T : class
    where P : class
{
    var expr = member.Compile();
    var memberName = ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member.Name;
    var value = expr(obj);

    bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(obj) { MemberName = memberName }, results);
    return isValid ? (onValidCallback != null ? onValidCallback(value) : value) : null;
}
```

And I simply call it like this:

```
var value = ValidateProperty(myObject, x => x.PropertyFoo, errors, result => result.Trim());
```

Which works like a charm and doesn't involve any magic strings being passed around.

A sample request would look like this:

```
public class Request
{
    public class C1
    {
        Property1;
        Property2;
        ...
    }
    public class C2
    {
        Property1;
        Property2;
        ...
    }
    public class C3
    {
        Property1;
        Property2;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My concern here however, is on performance implications for `member.Compile()`. Since there are many different possible permutations of `T, P` (`C1, Property1`, `C1, Property2`, `C2, Property1` etc.) I won't be able to cache the compiled expression and execute it on the next call, unless both `T` and `P` are of the same type, which happens rarely.

I could optimize this by changing `Expression<Func<T, P>> member` to `Expression<Func<T, object>> member` so that now I would have to only cache the expression once per type of `T` (i.e. `C1`, `C2`, etc.)

I was wondering if anyone has any input on a better way to do it, or am I trying to "over engineer" the problem? Is there a common pattern for situations that involve passing around magic strings over and over again?

Comment: This returns you back to the magic strings, but have you considered the new C#6 `nameof` operator instead od expressions?

Comment: Man, `nameof` is exactly what I need, but unfortunately we're stuck on C#5 for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option: Rather than using C# 6 features or compiling, just use reflection. Now you're trading compile performance degradation for reflection performance degradation (which is probably less).

```
...
var property = (PropertyInfo) ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member;
var propertyName = property.Name;
var value =  property.GetValue(obj, new object[0]);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are correct, `Expression.Compile` really has a significant performance overhead. If the performance is really a concern, and the reflection approach mentioned in another answer is still concerning you, here is how you can implement compiled delegate caching:

```
public static class ValidateUtils
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Delegate>> typeMemberFuncCache = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Delegate>>();

    public static P ValidateProperty<T, P>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, P>> member, List<ValidationResult> results, Func<P, P> onValidCallback = null)
        where T : class
        where P : class
    {
        var memberInfo = ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member;
        var memberName = memberInfo.Name;
        Func<T, P> memberFunc;
        lock (typeMemberFuncCache)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            Dictionary<string, Delegate> memberFuncCache;
            if (!typeMemberFuncCache.TryGetValue(type, out memberFuncCache))
                typeMemberFuncCache.Add(type, memberFuncCache = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>());
            Delegate entry;
            if (memberFuncCache.TryGetValue(memberName, out entry))
                memberFunc = (Func<T, P>)entry;
            else
                memberFuncCache.Add(memberName, memberFunc = member.Compile());
        }
        var value = memberFunc(obj);
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(obj) { MemberName = memberName }, results);
        return isValid ? (onValidCallback != null ? onValidCallback(value) : value) : null;
    }
}
```

Btw, I would remove `P : class` constraint, thus allowing validating also numeric, date etc. values, but anyway.

Comment: Does this seem like an overkill for not wanting to pass in strings though...?

Comment: Well, as I said, `nameof` is the best. Other than that, I wouldn't call it overkill, this is very similar to what `dynamic` does behind the scenes. And of course, use it **only** if you have performance issues. Reflection approach is probably the trade-off, I was going to suggest it to you as an option, but saw that another answer is targeting it.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6 (VS2015), you can use `nameof`. This call to your `ValidateProperty` method involves an extra parameter (name of property vs. value of property) which introduces a bit of redundancy but resolves your potential performance issue of compiling a bunch of stuff dynamically.

```
var value = ValidateProperty(myObject, nameof(PropertyFoo), PropertyFoo, errors, result => result.Trim());
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're not using C# 6 at the moment, but `nameof` is definitely what I'd need :/